# Can I publish only a subset of packages in one Turborepo, using Changesets?

Tags: javascript, monorepo, changeset, turborepo

As seen in the Turborepo docs, the monorepo can include [internal packages](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/sharing-code/internal-packages) in order to share code between apps inside the monorepo.

There is also a docs section on how to [publish packages in a monorepo](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/publishing-packages/versioning-and-publishing), via the [Changesets](https://github.com/changesets/changesets) CLI.

Is it possible to use changeset's version bumping for all the packages, but only publish one of the packages to the npm registry?

I know it is possible to [prevent all packages from being published](https://github.com/changesets/changesets/blob/main/docs/versioning-apps.md).

**Goal example**: After running `pnpm changeset` + `pnpm changeset version` + `pnpm changeset publish`, the `web` package is version-bumped while the `ui` package is both version-bumped *and* published to npm.